# Displaying array with xCode Cocoa App

Tags: arrays, xcode, macos, cocoa

Hi,
I m new in xcode programming, I would like to simply display an 2d array, exactly an ARR[2][26] using an component, I tried with an NSCollectionView, but I can't add my items, and I don't know if it's suitable for my need.
I need to display this array:
https://postimg.org/image/qvcdgdnkh/

could you give me an adequat way for displaying my array and access easily for each item.

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at a [Table Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [NSTableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview).

Comment: I want to have an array like this: https://postimg.org/image/qvcdgdnkh/